# Where do I find the update to allow a thumb drive to act as a hard drive, thus allowing me to play old Xbox games?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a bunch of old Xbox games I wanna play (the greats - Soulcalibur 2, ATV Quad Power Racing, Sonic Mega Collection Plus, etc.), so I go to my local Gamestop to ask for a hard drive for my Xbox 360 (as you may or may not know, backwards compatibility is only achieved through a hard drive). I tell the clerk more about my situation, and as luck would have it, he tells me that as long as I have a thumbdrive with more than 12 gigs on it - which I do, of course - it can act as that hard drive, allowing me to play old Xbox games. I just have to look for an update. Unfortunately, I have no idea what this update is titled, nor where I would even begin to look for it. Please help me soon or else I have to shell out $30+ for a new hard drive.

Comment: I think when they/you mean update, they/you really mean format.  You can follow [this page](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/using-usb-flash-drive) on how to format a thumb drive for the 360 to use.

Answer (score 0):

A external hard drive is not the only way to play old xbox games, plug your USB into your XBOX 360, then go into system. Next go into storage, select the USB then move all the game files to the Xbox's Built in storage